# Laravel migration modifier ->after('column') not working

Tags: laravel

Setting up migration for a table.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by')->nullable()->after('created_at');
        });
```

The issue is with `->after('created_at')`.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'after `created_at`) default character set
>   utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1 (SQL: create table
>   `users` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
>   `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null,
>   `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not null,
>   `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null, `created_by` bigint unsigned null after
>   `created_at`) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')]

**I'm using Laragon development platform.**

**mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Win64 (x86_64)**

Comment: remove `->after('created_at')` code from last line. because you are creating migration not updating.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya Oh geez. You're right. It's creating not modifying.